# GDAL translate to COG seems altering the original data image

Tags: raster, gdal, cloud-optimized-geotiff

Trying to compare with gdal info on both images, nothing seems been different but when trying preview images on QGIS with same band settings value, the image seems to be altered.

Command use for that :
`gdal_translate input.tif output.tif -of COG -co BLOCKSIZE=512 -co RESAMPLING=BILINEAR -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co NUM-THREADS=25 -co BIGTIFF=YES`

Tested on GDAL 3.2.2 Linux OS package and also with Docker images Alpine with GDAL 3.3.2
Any idea why my image is not just optimized but altered ?

[image: Orginal Data]

[image: COG translated data]

[image: QGIS band settings]

Comment: You ask to use `RESAMPLING=BILINEAR`. What if you NEAREST instead?

Comment: Usually NEAREST is good but this DEM seems displaying some square effect at very high resolution. BILINEAR fix that by homogenous render.

Comment: But you told that you do not want to alter data. Nearest should not alter anything if you do not re-project, as with your command.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I gonna retry without that but when I tried to preview into QGIS by changing nearest to bilinear render, nothing was altered.

Comment: Can you check that this happens as well as full resolution and is not an artefact of the overview generation process? E.g. subtract one raster from the other.

Comment: Oh god Jose, answer is so simple, when zooming, I can see full data, it's kind a vector simplification on the fly, you're right :o
At standard scale, data are identical.
Even no data pixel is present but at an high level zooming not on global view that is show on the COG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @user30187 and @Jose !

I've done a test without BILINEAR and not exactly same visual result but not much more looking as the non COG Tif file. So it wasn't that.

When zooming, I've got exactly the same data as the original tif file. It's kind of "an on the fly simplification" for vector data.

Tips with QGIS : when loading the bilinear COG file QGIS render stay with nearest that cause some artefact in the graphic render. So by switching to bilinear render QGIS, everything is ok.

Many thanks for your precious help !